# Populate a previously created associative array, with values

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to populate a previously created associative array, with values where values are randomly created. I cannot spot what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php

$value_min = 1;
$value_max = 3;

$my_array = array (
    "dice_1" => null,
    "dice_2" => null,
    "dice_3" => null
);

foreach(range($value_min, $value_max) as $key => $value) {
    $my_array[] = random_int($value_min, $value_max);
};

print_r($my_array);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Array
(
    [dice_1] => 
    [dice_2] => 
    [dice_3] => 
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

**Expected outcome**

```
(
    [dice_1] => 2  
    [dice_2] => 2
    [dice_3] => 3
)
```

> **Note:** value can of course diff since they are created with random numbers

Comment: I like the use of `range()` in the `foreach` loop, but you're not using the `$key` at all.

Comment: I think you are making your life harder here than it needs to be, by using these weird array indexes. Why not give the array _variable_ a proper name that indicates its purpose (maybe `$dice_throws` instead of `$my_array`), and use simple, zero-based indexing for the elements inside of it …?

Comment: @04FS Thanks for input. Your comment is valid in the term of name convention. When comes to array indexes there are situations where you "inherit" a structure and can change value but not key name convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the `foreach`

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
    $my_array[$key] = random_int($value_min, $value_max);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do something like this,

```
$t = range($value_min, $value_max);
shuffle($t);
$temp = array_combine(array_keys($my_array), $t);
```

I am fetching keys of `$my_array` and shuffled range array.
Then combining them as keys as first argument and shuffled range array as second argument.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4e910).

**EDIT**

In that case you can traverse my_array,

```
foreach($my_array as $key => &$value) { // & to save data directly to its address
    $value = random_int($value_min, $value_max);
};
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CVUXX).

Comment: I have previously tried your suggestion. Problem is that the combination of range and shuffle, only creates a series that is being shuffled. The result is that number 1 will always be created only once, etc. This removes the possibility for the dices to get a pair, e.g any throw that would have same number on different dices.

Comment: Ohk, I wasn't aware about this requirement, Please check my edited answer for your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value_min = 1;
$value_max = 3;

$my_array = array (
    "dice_1" => null,
    "dice_2" => null,
    "dice_3" => null
);

$i=1;
foreach(range($value_min, $value_max) as $key => $value) {
    $my_array["dice_".$i] = random_int($value_min, $value_max);
    $i++;
};

print_r($my_array);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85ab4ce3fd36d350b3461b51942084c79828ae12)